# How do I extract values of an array to use in a mathematical equation within a loop?

Tags: arrays

```
for i in (0,len(zeta)):
        os_s[i] = np.sqrt(np.dot(zeta[i],S.dot(zeta[i])))
        print(find_nearest(os_s, value=0.4))
    print("---------------------------")
```

The zeta is giving error.
I am getting

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [60], in <cell line: 2>()
     12 os_s = np.zeros(nobs)
     13 for i in (0,len(zeta)):
---> 14     os_s[i] = np.sqrt(np.dot(zeta[i],S.dot(zeta[i])))
     15     print(find_nearest(os_s, value=0.4))
     16 print("---------------------------")

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have tried extracting values in zeta to use in equation os_s within a loop for each zeta value.

Comment: The result of the np.sqrt is a sequence not an integer

Comment: Thanks, what is the remedy to  make this run?